# Preprocess Image for Opencv Dnn Classification

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv

I have a onnx model for classification. I am trying to classify some images with c++. I am reading onnx file and trying to predict with opencv dnn library.

While using python, I am preprocessing image with numpy. I am  creating 4d dimensional numpy array and filling it with image. Codes are below.

```
blob = np.full((1, imgHeight, imgWidth, 3), 0)
blob[0, :, :, :] = img
```

With this way blob's dimension order would be NHWC and I can use it for feeding model to classification. But when I use blobfromimage function, It gives me different output like NCWH. I can't feed model with this this way. When I use reshape function  for changing dimensins order, Model prediction was always same class.

blobfromimage function code is below.

```
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img,1.0, dsize, (0,0,0), False, False, cv2.CV_32F)
```

I am trying to do this process which takes positive results with C++ but I can't use numpy array library for C++. After long explanation, My problem is that, how can I preprocess images and creates NHWC cv::Mat object for feeding model to classification. I wasted my nearly 1 week for this problem.

Comment: I think you should create a raw array and copy image data there.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this.

```
cv::Mat img = ... 

auto img_size = img.rows * img.cols * 3;
std::vector<unsigned char> array(1 * img_size, 0);

std::copy(img.data, img.data + img_size, array.data());
```